# How to Set VisibilityTimeout to Indefinite and Manually Trigger Message Reappearance In Azure Storage Queue

Tags: c#, .net, azure-storage-queues

After receiving the message, is it possible to set visibilityTimeout to indefinite and manually trigger the message to reappear?

The reason for this is that my application processes the message before deleting it and the time it will complete may vary greatly. I need to make sure I don't process the same message twice.

I'm using c# and .net core for my application.

Answer (score 1):

In our application, we have used the next approach

1. receive the message
2. start background `Timer` extending the message visibility for another `60s` (see [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#change-the-contents-of-a-queued-message))
3. do the job in the main thread
4. if the job is done successfully - cancel `Timer` and remove message from the queue
5. if the job has failed, then we stop the timer, but don't remove the message so it became visible and give it another try
6. after a certain number of retries - remove the message

The main difference from Sampath's answer is that you don't need to wait until the end of 7 days or any other predefined time interval. It also implements the retry strategy

Answer (score 0):

> AFAIK, The time range is between `0`  to `604800`i.e : 0 sec to 7 days. I have referred to this  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues) for Azure Queue Storage. and git reference [@SreedharPelluru](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-resource-manager-exceptions.md).

[image]

```cs
     string connectionString = "connectionstring";
     QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, "QueueName");
     queueClient.CreateIfNotExists();       
     queueClient.SendMessage("Hello, World!");
     QueueMessage message = queueClient.ReceiveMessage();
  queueClient.UpdateMessage(message.MessageId, message.PopReceipt, message.MessageText, TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

- In the Azure portal it is possible to set  [message](https://i.imgur.com/ebtQnXN.png) never [expire](https://i.imgur.com/UoMom5S.png)